# Create custom projections in QGIS 3.10?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

QGIS does not have the coordinate reference system I need, So I decide to define a new custom Geographic coordinate system.To define a CRS, i have **srs.db** & **.wkt** file.
I place these file as 
(a) Copy SRS.db in the folder and paste this file in C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis\resources 
(b) Copy ESRI_EXTRA.wkt: paste this file in C:\Program Files\QGIS 18\share\gdal

After successful data import my custom CRS shown in predefined coordinate reference system:
[image: custom CRS]

Problem is when i try to these CRS for my project the CRS is Selectable. It shows check in No projection.
[image: eeror on selection of custom CRS]

Comment: The common way to include a custom CRS is through the Custom Projections menu dialog. But you can include custom projections in other ways. The No Projection mark is about the map, or canvas, of the project. You can just uncheck it and select any one of the projections (predefined and custom ones) for the map. That is not the CRS definition of the data in the layers. Can you uncheck it and select the CRS that you want for the map?

Comment: I need that MUTM CRS as in above image, how can i get ride of this?

Comment: As in the above image you have already that Modified UTM CRSes in QGIS. Of what do you need to get ride?

Comment: The problem is i can not choose(select) those new UTM for my project.

Comment: If you uncheck the No Projection mark, are not the custom CRS in the list of Predefined CRSes?

Comment: Do not understand question clearly but "if i uncheck the No Projection is selected" Appreciate your support to solve problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cant't understand your question or problem

Comment: No problem. I solved it using Lower version of QGIS 3.4.